# Enviar parâmetros para serviços Restfull

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-web-api

Tenho uma aplicação web mvc e nela tenho uma action que deverá passar uma parâmetro para um serviço REST. Como eu passo um parâmetro para um serviço REST. Sei que terei de implementar um HttpPost, mas como? Alguem conhece algum tuto que possa nos ajudar?

**EDIT1**

O seguinte. Imagine uma empresa matriz com 7 lojas. Cada loja com sua equipe de vendedores. Chega um cliente nessa loja e faz uma baita compra. É muito comum termos venda de mais de R$ 5.000,00. Nessa venda há vários itens. Bem, digamos que um dado cliente comprou insumos, vacinas e etc e deu aí 120.000,00. Como ele tem a grana, ele pede um prazo longo(até a colheita, talvez) um desconto. Acontece que esse desconto está além da capacidade do vendedor conceder, então ele starta o cara bem acima dele, que normalmente está na matriz. Como ele faz isso? Alterando uma flag no BD(FLAG_LIBERACAO) de 1 pra 0. É nesse momento que o sistema vai atuar. Essa alteração os desenvolvedores da empresa farão(sistema feito em Clarion/InterDev). O que acontece é, quando o cliente solicitar o desconto, o vendedor clica num botão que altera a Flag e já envia para o serviço(aqui entra meu sistema) a Solicitação(coloquei OK/Negar) mas pode ser qualquer coisa. Então o serviço pega essa informação recém chegada e dispara uma Push Notification(PN). E cada gerente/diretor recebe e faz o que tem que fazer. Há uma regra para cada um receber, mas isso é outra coisa e eu já estou trampando nisso. Espero ter ficado claro, mas se ainda houver dúvida, estou aqui para responder.

**EDIT2**

Montei a minha API assim:

```
public class GetValueLiberacao
    {
        [Route("api/postvalueliberacao/{value}")]
        [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
        public HttpResponseMessage PostValueLiberacao([FromBody] string value)
        {
            try
            {
                if (value == "Ok")
                {
                    Task t = new Task(async () =>
                    {
                        await SenderMessage();
                    });
                    t.Start();
                }

                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("OK")
                };

                return response;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created)
                {
                    Content = new StringContent("Falha \n" + ex.Message)
                };
                return response;
            }
        }

        public static async Task<IFCMResponse> SenderMessage()
        {
            FCMClient client = new FCMClient("AAAA0myCZjE:APA91bETPO0K3EtgBhHz_gMXDtBTiQrCsFaOW8wmFxbk5XvYhxTRIW9ZQR_mxNU8ThWe0d0A40JzG-Up_P2qyCw9hf6DrrRJfpynRIpnv_8FjIk3BsElnBuRenOi0h2r_h7Bv_"); //as derived from https://console.firebase.google.com/project/
            var message = new Message()
            {
                To = "APA91bGmgZnr2YMolubwS7c_e6AAkbVj6ga83lSHLo31FRUoom3iuS73PR1Bo6-iJEZWA88Xom7SWMrBK7edS6xVoe0kHdoIEowye4dsKXdtHdjd60_QEYcBkIi9QLyP7ZX6qdfdj", //topic example /topics/all
                Notification = new AndroidNotification()
                {
                    Body = "Solicitação de Novo Desconto",
                    Title = "Desconto",
                }
            };
            //CrossBadge.Current.SetBadge(1, "Teste");
            var result = await client.SendMessageAsync(message);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Caso eu receba **OK** no parâmetro, eu então disparo a Push Notification.
Agora estou trabalhando no consumo e envio do parâmetro, a partir de uma outra aplicação. A dúvida agora seria a controller, como ela ficaria, já que é por ela que o programa vai enviar os dados. Ainda não montei. Fiz apenas esse método e preciso montar a controller que vai fazer acontecer tudo isso. Vou necessitar de ***EnableCors***?

**EDIT3**
Fiz a minha controller assim:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/postvalueliberacao")]
    public class GetLiberaItensController : ApiController
    {
        AutorizadorContext contexto = new AutorizadorContext();
        GetValueLiberacao libitens = new GetValueLiberacao();

        [Route("{value}")]
        [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetLiberaItens(string value)
        {
            return libitens.PostValueLiberacao(value);
        }
    }
```

Vou começar a atestar. Primeiro no Postman e depois na minha aplicação.

Comment: você descreveu o que o aplicativo tem que fazer...você quer na verdade é criar a api ? É muito ampla e certamente será fechada... consumir uma api ? precisa da documentação dela, ou pelo menos saber como funciona...

Comment: Não é criar a API e sim, passar uma parâmetro para um serviço. Apenas isso. Só desenvolvi a minha regra para ficar mais claro. Só quero saber como eu envio um parâmetro, uma string, um bool, qualquer coisa para um REST.

Comment: então...precisa saber como essa api recebe isso, normalmente, na url, mas pode receber no header ou no content também

Comment: Tipo isso: http://meusite.com.br/autoriza/api/getparametro/{value}. Como envio de um desktop um parâmetro para ser pego no value de minha URL.

Comment: a api é sua ? mostre o codigo dela, rota...controller...qlqr coisa

Comment: Ainda estou fazendo e é uma da dúvidas quando o assunto é post, mas estou indo po este caminho: `[Route("api/getliberaitens/{value}")]
        [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
        public string PostValueLiberacao([FromBody] string value)
        {???????????????????
            return value;
        }`

Comment: Com a API acima, passando isso no Postman, deveria dar certo?`http://www.inetglobal.com.br/autorizador/api/postvalueliberacao/Ok`

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67329/discussion-between-rovann-linhalis-and-pnet).

Answer (score 2):

utilizo a seguinte função:

```
    public static string HttpPost(string url, string postData, string token)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        request.Headers["api-token"] = token;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        return responseString;
    }
```

Basta informar a url, os dados que serão enviados, no caso está para enviar um json, e o token que deve ir no header. Lembrando que isso é especifico para cada api, e você tem que consultar na documentação dela.

Edit:

considerando o seguinte código para a API:

```
    [ApplyModelValidation]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]string valor)
    {
        try
        {
             //faz qualquer processo...               
             return Ok("retorno: "+ valor);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }
```

Você iria consumi-la assim:

Método POST:

```
    public static string HttpPost(string url, string postData)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

        byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Accept = "text/plain";
        request.ContentType = "text/plain; charset=utf-8";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        return responseString;
    }
```

Consumindo:

```
public void Consumir()
{
    string retorno = HttPost("http://minhaapi.com.br/api/controller/","esse texto q eu estou enviando");

    //resultado: "retorno: esse texto q eu estou enviando";
}
```

espero que ajude, e, obviamente não testei, pode ter algum erro.

Comment: O que eu coloco nesse token? Não entendi o token. O que eu quero é enviar isso: "OK" ou "NEGADO" para o serviço e dependendo da resposta, ele envia uma notificação para o App Android. No serviço tem o código de envio de PN. Só preciso fazer um código que pegue o valor de uma flag no banco e envie uma dessas palavras para o serviço.

Comment: você perguntou como fazer o POST pra um serviço...você precisa de ter a documentação desse serviço... o token no caso, é porqueo serviço que eu utilizo, é autorizado por um token, se não tiver que enviar um token no header, é só remover

Comment: Então, essa é dúvida como enviar um parâmetro. Vou remover o token e ver se consigo enviar alguma coisa. Falta pouco pra terminar e à medida que avanço, coisas vão aparecendo, ehehe.

Comment: entendendo como parâmetro... seria na url... você também pode mandar pelo content, aí vai no corpo da request... se você colocar como a api funciona facilita o entendimento

Comment: @pnet veja se ajuda

Comment: Rovann, vou testar e depois ou amanhã, posto, pois já são 17:17. Eu fico até meia noite, mas caso não possamos mais falar por hoje, eu posto até amanhã. Vou começa a fazer e testar.

Comment: @pnet conseguiu resolver ?

Comment: Cara, tá dando um erro que não sei se é do provedor ou meu. Abri um chamado na redehost(provedor) para averiguar. Vou testar em localhost agora e ver o que acontece.